# Batch Run does not capture the Exception in Console

Tags: java, testng

Please find the simple program below:

```
package com.temp.practice;
import org.testng.SkipException;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

@Test
public class Exp1
{
   public void e1()
   {    
      System.out.println("Excpetion Test1");
      throw new SkipException("e1--- The test cases is not executed");
   }
}
```

If I execute the above code, I am receiving the `SkipException` in the console as expected.

[image]

But when I have the same kind of code in three different classes and execute them in a batch, the Skip exception is not captured in the console.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="SuiteName" >
<test name="ITest">
<classes>
<class name="com.temp.practice.Exp1"/>
</classes>
</test> <!-- TestB -->
<test name="StroSearch">
<classes>
<class name="com.temp.practice.Exp2"/>
</classes>
</test> <!-- TestB -->
<test name="full">
<classes>
<class name="com.temp.practice.Exp3"/>
</classes>
</test> <!-- TestB -->
</suite> <!-- SuiteName -->
```

What could be the reason?

Comment: 1) Which TestNG version you are using? 2) What is the content of `Default test.xml` (please provide it as text, not as an image).

Comment: Thanks for responding. 1) TestNg version : 6.9.13.201609291640  2)  I don't have test.xml. I have a file called Testng.xml , the script(text and image) is copied in my question.

Comment: In your first screeshot in the console window it's shown `[Utils] Attempting to create ... \Default test.xml`. Maybe you run the tests in different ways.

Comment: Yes, got the first screenshot result when I run the Exp1.java separately.( just right clicked and Run As->TestNg  2) Got the second screenshot result when I execute all (Exp1.java,Exp2.java and Exp3.java) the class using batch run by executing TestNg.xml

Comment: After you run the `Exp1.java` have a look into the generated `Default test.xml`.

Comment: here is the default test.xml                                                                          <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Default suite">
  <test verbose="2" name="Default test">
    <classes>
      <class name="com.temp.practice.Exp2"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Default test -->
</suite> <!-- Default suite -->

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you haven't specified the verbosity levels in your suite xml. Stacktraces are printed only when there's a verbosity of 2 or more defined in your suite xml. So to see the stacktraces

- **Change** `<suite name="SuiteName" >`
- **To** `<suite name="SuiteName" verbose="2">`
  and try again. You should see the exception stack-trace on your console.

Comment: Thanks a lot.This works. Now I am getting the exception in the console during Batch run.

Comment: Certainly! just did that